Terraform Pass Map to Module as a variable
It might be a very silly question. I have an idea but it doesn't work for me. I just wanted to ask the community if anyone has done something like this?
This is the sort of test scenario I have underlined
main.tf
variables.tf
env.tfvars
  |
  |__resource.tf
  |__variables.tf 

both the variables.tf have a map of objects defined in them:
variable "storageAccount" {
  type = map(
    object({
      name       = string
      CreatedBy  = string
    })
  )
  default = {
    "storageAccount" = {
       name      = ""
       CreatedBy = ""
    }
  }
}

The resource.tf is iterating over the map in variables to create multiple resources. Example:
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageAccount" {
  for_each  = var.storageAccount
  name      = each.value.name
  CreatedBy = each.value.CreatedBy
}

The main.tf has the module invocation, example:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    key_vault {
      recover_soft_deleted_secrets = false
    }
  }
  skip_provider_registration = true
}

module "storageAccount" {
  source         = "./modules"
  storageAccount = var.storageAccount
}

I believe I am trying to send the entire map in tfvars which may have lets say 2 resource configs in map defined and let the resource block then iterate over that. Is that a valid workflow as it seems that the resource.tf in my case is just getting nulls or blanks and throwing errors that the values cannot be blanks or nulls or doesn't match regex etc.
